# How to check if DateTime object is null

Tags: c#, datetime, isnullorempty

I'm looking to validate a `DateTime` variable to ensure that it isn't blank on the UI. The string equivalent checking would be `String.IsNullOrEmpty()`, but how would I go about it with my `DateTime` variable?

Comment: DateTime can't be null or empty.  What's the actual problem?

Comment: can you elaborate on your issue? one thing you can use its `DateTime.TryParse()`

Comment: Are you using a specific control like [DateTimePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker(v=vs.110).aspx) that has documentation?

Comment: @JuanC. My task is to take in a date of birth from a user interface, and the only validation that is asked of me is to throw an argument exception if the date of birth field is blank on the GUI when a button is clicked

Answer (score 5):

`DateTime` is a value type, so it cannot be null. To check if a `DateTime` variable has the default (all 0) value you can compare it with `new DateTime()` or `default(DateTime)`.

Another option would be to use `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime` for user input and check `HasValue` property.

Answer (score 2):

To check if a `DateTime` is null in C#, you must first ensure the DateTime is nullable.

```
// DateTime? means it is nullable
var DateTime? date = null;

// .HasValue only exists if DateTime is nullable
if(date.HasValue)
    Console.WriteLine("date has a value");
else
    Console.WriteLine("date is null");
```

If your `DateTime` is not nullable, make it nullable (unless you are absolutely certain in will never be null). You don't want to go down the road of assigning "nullish" values to your DateTimes. In my experience, this creates confusing bugs / code.